# Bootable cloud backup services?

Tags: backup, data-synchronization, storage

After investigating Box, Dropbox, Crashplan, Mozy, Carbonite, backblaze.com I'm struggling to find a service that offers all the following:

- Backs up files to the cloud, that is accessible 24/7 on mobile and
  web
- Can mail a bootable backup of your system on demand
- Works with macs

Does any service like this exist?

Comment: **"Can mail a bootable backup of your system on demand"** What, _exactly_, do you mean by this?

Comment: @IconDaemon - Backblaze, for instance, will mail a HD containing your backup if you request one [at a cost, of course] - but it is not bootable as Backblaze doesn't backup the system itself, just your data.

Answer (score 1):

My own solution to this problem, for both Macs here is

- Local Time Machine backups, hourly, on-site
- Backblaze once a night [best for my data plan]

That way, even if the building burns down, my maximum data loss is one day.
Backblaze is accessible from any web browser & files can be downloaded on demand; or if the data is huge, can be mailed on HD. It doesn't, however, contain the OS itself, only your data, prefs, settings etc.

Additionally, I swap out the Time Machine drives once a year, when I do any major upgrade - 10.10 to 10.11 etc.

I also make sure I have at least one clone of the current boot drive, though I don't keep it up to date on any regular basis. It will contain enough historical data - old installs I've lost the disks for, audio plugins where the authorisation site no longer exists, etc.

I also make sure to have Recovery Partitions on more than one drive.

A further step would be to have an additional Time Machine drive, which normally lives off-site.

I just checked - [Backblaze is also available for iOS & Android](https://www.backblaze.com/mobile.html) - though it's not something I've ever really investigated.